# python CGI call new subprocess without waiting

Tags: python, subprocess, cgi

I have read various posts here about the problem of starting another python script inside one that is being called by a CGI i.e., I have an apache2 server running on a Raspberrypi with CGI enabled.

1) from a browser : webform data is sent to the CGI interface and it calls my python script `test1.py`

2) from `test1.py` I want to call `test2.py` (which will run forever or for whatever time needed (it updates continuously values somewhere)

3) the point is : I want the CGI script to IMMEDIATELY display some result let's say "test2 has started" on a "result webpage" AND run in background my `test2.py`

However what happends is that the webpage with the form just waits forever that my test2.py finishes!

I have tried things like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/var/www/cgi-bin/test2.py'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

But this does not work (i.e. waits for the script test2 to finish...)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is this link .[getting start Cgi programmin](https://www.w3resource.com/python/cgi-programming.php)

The answer to your second question: You should use multi-threaded programming.

If you have sample function in module test2 ...

```
#in test1.py
import threading
import test2
T1 = threading.Thread(test2.sample(object))
T1.start()
```

Answer your third question:
Then you can either make a folder in your site's path where your cgi files will live, or configure certain directories to handle certain file types as cgi scripts.
This is described well in the apache2 doc above, but essentially you to make all files in a cgi folder be executed, you would use this conf:

Options ExecCGI
        SetHandler cgi-script

and to allow .py files to be executed as scripts in a particular folder you would use this conf:

```
<Directory /srv/www/yoursite/public_html>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Once you have that, if you're running python 3, you can make a python script like this one, and stick it in whichever folder is configured for cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()    print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()    print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer! In fact i have set up CGI etc it is working (e.g. with a short script its ok) my problem is to launch a long script from the CGI and then not wait but immediately show a webpage

Answer (score 0):

thanks this is a great answer!

I just added this to my script test1.py (atm no function in test2.py just raw code):

[...]
import test2
cgitb.enable()

T1 = threading.Thread(test2)
T1.start()

[...]

However the webpage still waits forever although i noticed that the test2 is indeed launched by the thread...
do you have an idea how to make the webpage display something instead of waiting?

Please note that i have also tried that:

```
pid = os.fork()
#if pid==0 then we are in the child process
if(pid==0):
    T1 = threading.Thread(test2)
    T1.start()
    #i would hope that here the child process is detached from making wait the CGI!! but no
else:
    print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
    print('<h1>Python Script Test</h1>')
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    tempThVal = form['tempThresh'].value
    print('Temperature threshold= ' + tempThVal)
```

But still the damned browser is waiting for it to finish!!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can combine your own solution with my answer to get the right answer.

```
#in test1.py

class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/var/www/cgi-bin/test2.py'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        ########################
        #or your test2 statment#
        ########################
pid = os.fork()
#if pid==0 then we are in the child process
if(pid==0):
    T1 = my_thread()
    T1.start()
#i would hope that here the child process is detached from making wait the CGI!! but 
no
else:
   print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
   print('<h1>Python Script Test</h1>')
   form = cgi.FieldStorage()
   tempThVal = form['tempThresh'].value
   print('Temperature threshold= ' + tempThVal)
```

I used this method to solve this problem in the Django framework

Comment: thanks! This is very interesting, i will try it today. Thanks alot for your very fast answers.

Comment: just tested it... still same problem (page is waiting forever the end of test2, but does indeed start test2 as usual) :'((( really frustrating !!!  any other ideas ? maybe something with cron ?

Answer (score 0):

let me maybe just post my latest code (in case you might find something):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import threading
import test2
cgitb.enable()

class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '/var/www/cgi-bin/test2.py'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        ########################
        #or your test2 statment#
        ########################
pid = os.fork()
#if pid==0 then we are in the child process
if(pid==0):
    pid = os.fork()
    if(pid==0):
        T1 = my_thread()
        T1.start()
else:
   print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
   print('<h1>Python Script Test</h1>')
   form = cgi.FieldStorage()
   tempThVal = form['tempThresh'].value
   print('Temperature threshold= ' + tempThVal)
```

Comment: I wonder if the fact that i am receiving data from a form in this CGI might cause some problem (although i could not imagine why?)